# How do I include a custom JavaScript file in a module?

Tags: javascript

I want to include a custom JavaScript file in a module using the following code.

```
function profile2_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  drupal_add_js('http://localhost/prf2.js', 'external');
}
```

I then add `scripts[] = js/prf2.js` in the .info file, but it throws this error.

> Warning: file_get_contents(js/prf2.js): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in drupal_build_js_cache()

Comment: drupal_add_js('http://localhost/prf2.js','external'); Is "localhost" really the appropriate domain? Consider what happens when the client tries to load this JavaScript.

Comment: You are almost certainly going about this incorrectly since you are hacking the profile2 module rather than adding the javascript from your own custom module.

Comment: If am I add this inside profile2.module then how to access the js file. Please clarify your above code.

Comment: 1) I suggest we clarify something first. There is probably no need to modify (or hack, as it's often called) the profile2 module, so don't. 2) My code is 4 lines long, even counting the line `);`. If you don't understand it, you need to be more precise about what you need clarified.

Comment: @Letharion Passing the second parameter as a 'type' string is actually fine, it's only if you pass an associated array you need to use `'type' => 'external'`

Comment: @Clive Ah, I see you're right, the value is used to populate the 'type' value if it's just a string. Thanks. I've removed that piece of code.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is the right & simple way to include any JS file in Drupal 7.

1. Create a folder named i.e. `js`, inside your module folder.
2. Inside that folder place `(modulename).js` file.

   Note: Drupal JS code has a specific format as follows:

   ```
   (function ($) {
     $(document).ready(function(){
       alert("Hello world!");  //here we can add our JS code
     });
   })(jQuery);
   ```
3. Open `(modulename).info` file & add:

   `scripts[] = js/(modulename).js`
4. Clear Cache & Run.

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of documentation about how to include a JS file into a custom module or into your theme in general. Here is the official article: https://www.drupal.org/node/304255

There are plenty of examples and you can inspire yourself with it.

PS: Don't hardcode the path of your JS file as you did in your code. Use the drupal_get_path function.

Comment: <?php
drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'profile2') .'/prf2.js');
?>

.info file => scripts[] = js/prf2.js

Error occured

Comment: May u pls tell me I have to add script[]=js/prf2.js is compulsory..

Comment: If you do the drupal_add_js, you doesn't have to do it in the .info file.

Comment: Depending on your situation, you can choose to add your JS file in your theme, in your module .info file, in a module's hook, in a form...

Comment: My condition is I have a module i.e. profile2 & I have added some JS code to create condition between fields. My JS file is put inside js folder i.e. profile2.js. So in profile2.module I want to include JS. Then which condition is good for me.

Comment: When ever I use drupal_get_path... It shows an error "Fatal error: Class name must be a valid object or a string"

Comment: You cannot override a contrib module code! You should do the process through a custom module that you write yourself. Please read the documentation to see how to create a custom module https://www.drupal.org/developing/modules/7

Answer (score 0):

Here is two place where you can add JavaScript: In a theme or in a module.

#### 1. Theme

If you want to add JavaScript in theme simply go in `your_theme.info` file and add your file path for example if your theme directory is:

```
mytheme\
 \js\my_theme.js
 \my_theme.info
```

So write down:

```
scripts[] = js/my_theme.js
```

Under your `my_theme.info`
clear cache from admin and that should be work

#### 2. Module

I you want to add js in module then

```
my_module
my_module\js\my_module.js
my_module.module
```

In my_module.module call hook:

```
function my_module_init(){
    drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'my_module').'/js/my_module.js');
}
```

Above code add JavaScript once module enable.

Comment: function profile2_init(){ 
drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'profile2').'/js/profile2.js'); 
}

-------add this in my profile2.module

Comment: scripts[] = js/profile2.js----- add this in my profile2.info.. Its not working